# Setting up reverse dns on windows azure?

Tags: azure, reverse-dns

Does anyone know if this is possible? Browsing around on the internet I found out that it had been put on the roadmap but that was quite a way back. Has anyone achieved this? It seems odd that such a big player in the hosting industry doesn't offer this, as AWS does.

Also, I'm talking about reverse dns on virtual machines not the ip addresses of cloud services. I assumed it was something to do on the configuration of the linux machine, since the virtual machines have root access I thought this may have been possible, although struggling to find info on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like *Reverse DNS* feature is planned but I was not able to find more details on any timeline / planned release date.

You can find out more on those features on [Provide Reverse DNS for the Azure Virtual Machines](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/3090834-provide-reverse-dns-ptr-records-for-virtual-mach) as well as [reverse DNS lookup](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/170031-sdk/suggestions/1327391-reverse-dns-lookup) proposals on [Windows Azure Feature Voting](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com) website.

**EDIT**
As pointed out by @franzo, Windows Azure platform now support reverse DNS records at **no** additional cost. Reverse DNS support is for all PaaS and IaaS Cloud Services. You can find out more about that feature on [Announcing: Reverse DNS for Azure Cloud Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/21/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/).

Comment: It appears so, quite a shame. Thanks

Comment: It's been asked for from as far back as 2010. I would not have the hopes high. As of 15th Aug 2013 it's still "on the roadmap".

Comment: It's now available: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/21/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/

Comment: Note, in the new Azure Portal, you can't currently set up reverse DNS if you selected the Resource Manager deployment model when you created your VM (so use Classic instead).