# Failing to connect to MySQL from MVC4 app on Azure Website

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

I am attempting to connect to an existing MySQL database, which is not hosted on Azure, from an ASP.NET MVC4 web application (default "internet"), deployed in an Azure Website. I simplified as much as possible to illustrate the problem:

1) I added to my MVC app MySql.Data and MySql.Web via Nuget
2) I wrote the following ugly code in the default HomeController, in the About() method:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    try
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        Trace.TraceInformation("Connection String");
        var connStr =
            "server=blah.blah.com;user=someone;database=somedatabase;port=3306;password=password;";

        Trace.TraceInformation("Connection");
        var connection = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

        Trace.TraceInformation("Open Connection");
        connection.Open();

        Trace.TraceInformation("Close Connection");
        connection.Close();

        return View();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.TraceError("{0} / {1} / {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.TargetSite);
        throw;
    }
}
```

This runs without a glitch on my local machine when I debug (I have no problem retrieving data either), but the moment I publish to the Azure Website, if fails miserably. The Trace produced is the following:

```
2013-07-31T03:05:02  PID[20636] Information Connection String
2013-07-31T03:05:02  PID[20636] Information Connection
2013-07-31T03:05:02  PID[20636] Information Open Connection
2013-07-31T03:05:09  PID[20636] Error       Can't get hostname for your address
2013-07-31T03:05:09  PID[20636] Error       Can't get hostname for your address /    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at MvcTest.Controllers.HomeController.About() / MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPacket ReadPacket()
```

Can anybody help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Is there a specific reason why this would fail from an Azure Website and not my local machine? Note: my local machine is not on the same network as the MySQL database, or anything like that.

Comment: This is just speculation but it appears there is a problem resolving your machines name. Check out this long thread where someone had the same sort of problem http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I am gathering, the issue is that MySQL uses by default reverse DNS lookup, which at the time being is not supported by Azure:

[Reverse DNS lookup on Windows Azure?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/73597a20-e8dd-43cd-9265-428dfa04873c/reverse-dns-lookup-on-windows-azure)
[Setting up reverse dns on windows azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695233/setting-up-reverse-dns-on-windows-azure)

It looks like it is possible to [turn off MySQL reverse DNS lookup](https://serverfault.com/questions/341290/mysql-warning-ip-address-could-not-be-resolved), but I haven't been able to try it yet (the existing DB is not under my control).

Comment: It's been implemented now: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/